# Create table - Mysql

Tags: mysql, create-table

I'm looking for a little help with this table.  First:  The table isn't being accepted by mysql. I'm getting a 150 error, which doesn't tell me much.  Second, I'm very certain that I'm not using the best data types & way to go about things.... please give me a little input!

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `axis`.`Employee` (
`idEmployee` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`idAccount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`user` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`pass` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`firstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`lastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`middleName` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`idGrp` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`idCompany` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`idLocation` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`idUnit` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`idCrew` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`idPosition` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`officeLoc` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`wPhone` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`wCell` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`wFax` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`wEmail` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`radio` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`hPhone` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`hCell` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`hEmail` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`addrOne` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`addrTwo` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`city` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`state` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`zip` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`emergContact` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`emergPhone` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`gender` ENUM('male','female') NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`birthDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`ssn` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`hireDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`sepDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`comment` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`photo` MEDIUMBLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`isActive` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
`allowLogin` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`trackTravel` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
`trackTimesheet` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
`defFltArr` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`defFltDep` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`defDayTimeStart` TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '06:00:00' ,
`defHoursPerDay` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '11.50' ,
`userType` ENUM('root','admin','view','acl','report','employee') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'employee',
`created` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`modifiedBy` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`idEmployee`, `idAccount`, `idGrp`, `idCompany`, `idLocation`, `idUnit`, `idCrew`, `idPosition`, `modifiedBy`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQUE` (`idEmployee` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Employee_Grp` (`idGrp` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Employee_Company` (`idCompany` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Employee_Unit` (`idUnit` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Employee_Location` (`idLocation` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Employee_Crew` (`idCrew` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Employee_Position` (`idPosition` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Employee_Employee` (`modifiedBy` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Grp`
FOREIGN KEY (`idGrp` )
REFERENCES `axis`.`Grp` (`idGrp` )
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Company`
FOREIGN KEY (`idCompany` )
REFERENCES `axis`.`Company` (`idCompany` )
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Unit`
FOREIGN KEY (`idUnit` )
REFERENCES `axis`.`Unit` (`idUnit` )
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Location`
FOREIGN KEY (`idLocation` )
REFERENCES `axis`.`Location` (`idLocation` )
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Crew`
FOREIGN KEY (`idCrew` )
REFERENCES `axis`.`Crew` (`idCrew` )
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Position`
FOREIGN KEY (`idPosition` )
REFERENCES `axis`.`Position` (`idPosition` )
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Employee`
FOREIGN KEY (`modifiedBy` )
REFERENCES `axis`.`Employee` (`idEmployee` )
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Not yet, I'm using the mysql workbench.  Time to hit up ssh.  I'll let you know what i find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many mistakes :

```
`idGrp` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL`
```

then

```
PRIMARY KEY (`idEmployee`, `idAccount`, `idGrp`, ... )
```

(Column that is part of PRIMARY KEY must be `NOT NULL` - mysql silently makes it `not null`,
finally

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Grp` FOREIGN KEY (`idGrp` ) 
 REFERENCES `axis`.`Grp` (`idGrp` ) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

(which is impossible - `ON DELETE SET NULL` - column is `not null`.

And why do you create composite key at all? `auto_increment` column uniquely identifies your record. All other stuff is redundant. It might possible make sense in some cases for `MyIsam` tables (I would not recommend to use it anyway), because a value for `auto_increment` column will be generated differently if it's a part of composite index , but not for `INNODB` engine.

Comment: That's some really great input... I didn't know a primary key couldn't be null, it does make sense though.  It looks like mysql workbench made all the foreign keys primary, when editing the relationship.  It seems I can't undo that.

Comment: This was the problem!  I changed the keys to Not Null, and the ON DELETE to No Action.  Why is there a "set null" if a foreign key has to be not null?

Comment: Foreign key column can be null, but if it's a part of primary then it cannot be null. I agree, mysql may generate a better error message in such cases

Comment: For some reason workbench is forcing the foreign keys to by primary.  I will look into this, perhaps there's something amiss.

Comment: You are definitely missing something. In mysql foreign key automatically creates an index on this column, but it doesn't have to be a primary index

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I may be very wrong, but are you allowed to have more than one Primary Key? I thought the whole purpose was that it was indeed a Primary (Unique) Key.

Comment: Yes, you can combine columns to create a composite primary key

Comment: The idEmployee is listed under the UNIQUE index. Is this not where it's suppose to go?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to a1ex07's reply, see this thread:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,259716#msg-259716

It might also be due to signed/unsigned integer-related problems.

Also, your primary key (a unique, not null (set of) field(s)) is, de facto, your employee ID, based on the table's definition.